# Unwanted blank table row in Docmosis

Tags: tornado, docmosis

I am using Docmosis to generate data into a table. A blank row appears underneath the table heading and between each row containing data.

I suspect my issue is occurring because of the statements using: `<<$isLender>>`
I have considered using `<<else_` to handle behaviour when `<<$isLender>>` is true or false however can't seem to find a working solution to remove the blank row. Any advice would be appreciated.

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
|  | `<<rr_submittingConveyancer.representees>>` |
|  | `<<$isLender=false>><<rs_party.roles>><<cs_{type=’lender’}>><<$isLender=true>><<es_{type=’lender’}>><<es_party.roles>>` |
|  | `<<cr_$isLender>>` |

[Full code for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Jk7.png)

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| Joe Bloggs | A1 address of the property |
|  |  |
| Big Company | B1 Current proprietor's address |

Comment: Welcome! "_Any advice would be appreciated._" Since this site is for _complete_ answers to _precise_, on-topic questions, can you please ask a precise question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a cell/row are not automatically removed even if the expressions etc result in a blank.

In this case, you have logic to calculate `$isLender` in a row by itself.  The simplest solution is to move that logic into the cell with the `<<rr_submittingConveyancer.representees>>`.  The variable will be set, but not leave a row in the output.